# Hypervolume of irregular convex polygons

Tags: geometry, approximation, volume, computational-geometry, convex-geometry

I would like to compute volumes of irregular d-dimensional, convex shapes. In principle, I know the equations of hyperplanes that bound the polygon.

In d=2, I could proceed with an algorithm as follows: I can easily compute the N vertices of my polygon by intersections of bounding lines, then I can compute the areas of the N triangles defined by one edge and a fixed random internal point (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula or equivalent) and sum the total area.

Does exist something similar in d>2 (or even alternative), that is computationally fast?

It's ok also a good approximations, I don't really need the exact volume.
I thought about something similar to [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pick's_theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pick%27s_theorem), using a multidimensional lattices, but I'm not sure it is the best idea by a computational point of view.

Comment: Are you sure that you can still calculate the vertices of your polyhedra _easily_ when dimension is arbitrary? I think it is not within polynomial growthrate w.r.t. d.

Comment: @donaastor quite sure I cannot (easily), maybe in a recursive manner I could figure out how to calculate vertices, but then I don't know any generalization of Heron formula in R^d (maybe this https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cayley-MengerDeterminant.html ?)

Comment: all these things are for simplexes which are far far simpler than you lr general case. I am afraid that you can't calculate it exactly. The number of edges is also not polynomial w.r.t. d. So, these matrices should only complicate things. Are you concerned about some specific dimension?